# Issue connecting GitLab runner with GitLab

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

GitLab is currently running on a given host as container and i am trying to setup GitLab runner on the same host in another container:

GitLab script (`GitLab version: 9.3.9`):

```
[root@rado1 gitlab_runner]# cat gitlab.sh
#!/bin/bash
sudo docker run --detach \
     --hostname gitlab.example.com \
     --publish 443:443 --publish 80:80 --publish 2222:22 \
     --name gitlab \
     --restart always \
     --volume /mnt/data/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
     --volume /mnt/data/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
     --volume /mnt/data/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
     gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

GitLab Runner script:

```
[root@rado1 gitlab_runner]# cat gitlab_runner.sh
docker run --name gitlab-ci-multi-runner -d --restart=always \
  --volume /mnt/data/gitlab/gitlab-runner:/home/gitlab_ci_multi_runner/data \
  --env='CI_SERVER_URL=http://gitlab/ci' --env='RUNNER_TOKEN=6cE9HefxGFfbAdadS4eT' \
  --env='RUNNER_DESCRIPTION=runnerA' --env='RUNNER_EXECUTOR=shell' \
  --link gitlab \
  sameersbn/gitlab-ci-multi-runner:1.1.4-7
```

GitLab is running on HTTPS.

Now when i try running `gitlab_runner.sh`, i get the following error:

```
ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 runner=6cE9Hefx 
status=couldn't execute POST against http://gitlab/ci/api/v1/runners/register.json: 
Post http://gitlab/ci/api/v1/runners/register.json: 
dial tcp 172.17.0.2:80: getsockopt: connection refused
PANIC: Failed to register this runner. Perhaps you are having network problems
```

I can see that `172.17.0.2` is GitLab IP only as shown below in Rancher UI:

[image]

Comment: Is the gitlab running on https?

Comment: Yes. It's on HTTPS only and CA signed, not self-signed.

Comment: Shouldn't the url be then `https://gitlab/ci/` ?

Comment: I tried that and i get the following error: `x509: certificate is valid for gitlab.dev.abc.net, *.gitlab.dev.abc.net, gitlab.abc.net, *.gitlab.abc.net, not gitlab`. So i guess i will have to change the name of the container to may be `gitlab.abc.net`, correct? If that's the case, i hope the mounted volume (`/mnt/data/gitlab`) will not get affected, correct?

Comment: Thanks @TarunLalwani for the `HTTPS` hint. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got it working. I renamed the container to `gitlab.abc.net` and updated the config for *gitlab runner* script to the following:

```
[root@rado1 gitlab_runner]# cat gitlab_runner.sh
docker run --name gitlab-ci-multi-runner -d --restart=always \
  --volume /mnt/data/gitlab/gitlab-runner:/home/gitlab_ci_multi_runner/data \
  --env='CI_SERVER_URL=https://gitlab.abc.net/ci' --env='RUNNER_TOKEN=6cE9HefxGFfbAdadS4eT' \
  --env='RUNNER_DESCRIPTION=runnerA' --env='RUNNER_EXECUTOR=shell' \
  --link gitlab.abc.net \
  sameersbn/gitlab-ci-multi-runner:1.1.4-7
```